# Magento Upgrading Magento 1.3 to 1.4 Class 'File' not found Cache.php

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.3

Upgrading from Magento 1.3 ( using full package -> overwrite ) . I get

Fatal error: Class 'file' not found in /home/www/r2h/mysite.net/public/lib/Zend/Cache.php on line 153

Something to do with the cache I guess..?  I have cleared apc and there is no file in /app/etc to delete which usually clears the cache.

I'm a bit baffled now.?  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.4 and newer works a bit different on clearing the cache.

That file named `cache.ser` (I think that's the name) no longer exists and its function has been moved into the core_cache_option table in the database. [Turn off Cache in Database.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24170/how-can-i-disable-the-cache-via-the-database)

To manually clear the Magento cache, delete all the subdirectories in `app/var/cache`.

Comment: ok - I guess the problem is that it hasn't actually upgraded.  I copied entire site , got it working as a copy of 1.3 , then overwrote with 1.4 files which is supposed to upgrade DB. There is no cache.ser file , and there is no core_cache_option table in the database. :-(  Maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

ok - Found the answer.  I was overwriting my 1.3 files instead of starting with a clean directory and updating the database - then moving themes, extensions etc over.